# I need to succesfully validate my xml file against xsd schema in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

when i run the code after adding both xml and xsd schema file i get the error as "ID" attribute not declared,The element 'Student' has invalid child element 'Student'.
Validation failed
below is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Students>
  <Student ID="101">
    <Name>kamal</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Marks>800</Marks>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="102">
    <Name>Sapna</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <Marks>900</Marks>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="103">
    <Name>Raju</Name>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Marks>870</Marks>
    <Student ID="104">
      <Name>Sushant</Name>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <Marks>700</Marks>
    </Student>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Students">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Student" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xsd:element name="Gender" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xsd:element name="Marks" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

And finally the code file:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    class Class16
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlSchemaSet ss = new XmlSchemaSet();
            ss.Add("", @"C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\Students.xsd");
             
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\sample1.xml");
             
            bool validationerror = false;
            doc.Validate(ss,(s,e)=>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                   validationerror = true;
                });
            if(validationerror)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validation failed");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Validation succeded");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change in both XSD as well as in you sample.xml. For your reference Please find below correct XSD and xml files.

Correct Sample:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Students>
          <Student ID="101">
            <Name>kamal</Name>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Marks>800</Marks>
          </Student>
          <Student ID="102">
            <Name>Sapna</Name>
            <Gender>Female</Gender>
            <Marks>900</Marks>
          </Student>
          <Student ID="103">
            <Name>Raju</Name>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Marks>870</Marks>
            </Student>
            <Student ID="104">
              <Name>Sushant</Name>
              <Gender>Male</Gender>
              <Marks>700</Marks>
            </Student>
        </Students>
```

Correct XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xsd:element name="Students">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Student" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4">
                  <xsd:complexType>     
                    <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="Name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                      <xsd:element name="Gender" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                      <xsd:element name="Marks" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                  </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
```

Comment: You tell what did you change here!

Comment: I have added <xsd:attribute name="ID" type="xsd:string" use="required" /> in XSD

Comment: and in XML, you have not closed one student element properly. So I have done that. If you observe carefully, 3rd student element in your XML file, you can find that it closing tag is just shifted to the end. Because of this you are getting error "The element 'Student' has invalid child element 'Student'"

Comment: can you share the wrong XML also, So that i can analyse